# DRF default_manager error?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My DRF based API is throwing an error which I can't seem to resolve as its not indicating an error coming from my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 83, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 477, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 437, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 448, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 474, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 40, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 151, in filter_queryset
    queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/filterset.py", line 28, in __init__
    super(FilterSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/drf_app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 284, in __init__
    queryset = self._meta.model._default_manager.all()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

Is the error in the rest-framework code or is it coming from elsewhere?

FYI, the django admin side works okay.

Below are the models and serializers am using:

```
class ListCreateRetrieveUpdateViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                                      mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                                      viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`, `update` actions.
    """
    pass


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class model that provides self updating
    ``created`` and ``modified`` fields.
    """
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                   related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by", editable=False)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_modified_by", editable=False)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Delete Entry')
    deleted_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_deleted_by",
                                   null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Country(BaseModel):
    """
    List of Countries
    """
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.code, self.title)

class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize model"""

    class Meta:
        model = Country

class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    list and create countries
    """
    end_point_name = 'CoreApp'
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
    filter_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: The problem is that the model is missing. Does this request enter in the ListCreateRetrieveUpdateViewSet which does not have anything set?

Comment: Kindly ellaborate on `Model is missing`. I have the `Country` model which inherits from `BaseModel` which is built from `models.Model`. Also what do you mean by `does the request enter in the ...`? Let me know I'll clarify. That Viewset is pretty much a copy paste from [DRF documentation as seen this link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example_3)

Comment: After much struggle I rebuilt my app one model and setting after the other and came across the issue of `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS`. Since a couple of days back I'd upgraded to DRF `3.5.1`, I had changed the filter backends to use `('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend', 'django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet',)` but if I uncomment that stuff works. I've posted an [issue on github](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4630)

Comment: The ListCreateRetrieveUpdateViewSet does not do anything because it does not have serializer, queryset set. What I wanted to say is that if you have a route that points to this viewset and you will enter to that route you will get error because of the missing serializer and queryset. As the DRF documentation says:
`To use it, override the class and set the .queryset and .serializer_class attributes.`

Comment: The `CountryViewSet` is actually `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` and the error still occurs. It does not inherit from `ListCreateRetrieveUpdateViewSet` like other views I have. I probably shouldn't have copied it here. Unless am missing something coz the CountryViewSet has got queryset and serializer attributes

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue today : it seems that since DRF 3.5, [filters classes have completely moved to django-filter package](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.5-announcement/#djangofilterbackend). I fixed my import statements, and all went smoothly. Hope it helps you !

> The functionality of the built-in DjangoFilterBackend is now completely included by the django-filter package.
>
> You should change your imports and REST framework filter settings as
> follows:
>
> `rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend` becomes `django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend`.
> `rest_framework.filters.FilterSet` becomes `django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet`.
>
> The existing imports will continue to work but are now pending deprecation.

In my case, the last sentence was false, it was not working.

Comment: Yap. I've confirmed. Its only `django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet` that is throwing an error and if I replace it with the original `rest_framework.filters.FilterSet` things work again. As seen in my comment above, I raised it as a bug but it was closed. Well, guess its something wrong with our code we just need to figure it out..